# Find the greatest value of $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If one of the roots of the equation $(a-b)x^2+ax+1=0$ is double of the other and is real , 
>   find the greatest value of $b$.

$\color{green}{a.)\ \dfrac98} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad b.)\ \dfrac87\\
c.)\ \dfrac86 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad d.)\ \dfrac75 $

I tried ,

By sum and product of roots formula,

Let one of the root be $\alpha$.

$$\begin{align}3\alpha&=\dfrac{-a}{a-b}\\
\implies 9\alpha^{2}&=\dfrac{a^2}{(a-b)^2}\\
2\alpha^{2}&=\dfrac{1}{a-b} \end{align}$$

And by discriminant I got $$a^2-4(a-b)\geq 0$$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{9\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2}=\dfrac{a^2}{a-b}$$

$$\implies9b=9a-2a^2=-2\left(a-\dfrac94\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac94\right)^2\le2\left(\dfrac94\right)^2$$ as $a$ is real

Comment: how did u get this part from $-2\left(a-\dfrac94\right)^2+2\left(\dfrac94\right)^2\le2\left(\dfrac94\right)^2$

Comment: @RK, As $a-9/4$ is real, $$\left(a-\dfrac94\right)^2\ge0\iff-\left(a-\dfrac94\right)^2\le0$$

Answer (score 1):

$3\alpha=\frac{-a}{a-b},
2\alpha^2=\frac{1}{a-b}$
divide
$\frac{3\alpha}{2\alpha^2}=-a$,
$a\alpha=\frac{-3}{2}...............(1)$,
As $\alpha$ is a root of $(a-b)x^2+ax+1=0$,
$(a-b)\alpha^2+a\alpha+1=0$
$(a-b)\frac{9}{4a^2}-\frac{3}{2}+1=0$
$2a^2-9a+9b=0$
this is quadratic in $a$ and as $a$ being real
$81-4(2)(9b)\ge0$
$b\le\frac{9}{8}$